# Send generated values in test as parameters to fixture in pytest

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

Let me give you and idea of what the test is about.
In this test, I'm calling an API that basically generates a file and an item in a DynamoDB table. The response the service, gives me the UUID that I use to look into the DB and check that everything is created correctly.
However, I cannot do the teardown in fixture because the uuid I need to delete item in dynamo is generated in the test. Right now, I'm deleting the item in the test but I wanted to do it in the fixture but I'm not sure if its possible to pass this uuid to the fixture.
Any suggestions or ideas?

```
@pytest.fixture
def prepare_test(self):
    body = open(self._filepath, "r")
    yield body

def test_post_template_tyc_happy_path(self, prepare_test):
    body = prepare_test
    response_body = self._tyc_api.post_template_contract(body.read(), header, 'LOAN', 'GOBIERNO', 'AUTOMATED_QA_TEST')
    result_dynamo = self._tyc_crud.find_contract_by_product_id_and_tac_version_id_async(response_body['productId'], response_body['tacVersionId'])

    assert response_body['productId'] == 'LOAN'
    assert response_body['tacVersionId'][:-36] == 'GOBIERNO#'
    assert response_body['description'] == 'AUTOMATED_QA_TEST'
    assert response_body['isLastVersion'] is True

    assert result_dynamo.description == 'AUTOMATED_QA_TEST'
    assert result_dynamo.tac_id == 'GOBIERNO'

    self.delete_test_data(response_body['productId'], response_body['tacVersionId'])

def delete_test_data(self, product_id, tac_version_id):
    self._tyc_crud.delete_contract_by_product_id_and_tac_version_id(product_id, tac_version_id)
```

Thanks!

Comment: but your fixture doesn't deal with dynamo at all, that doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: You should consider closing the file at some point or using a context manager.

Comment: @gold_cy oh ok, so you think it's a good enough to leave the deleation in the test? Just like I did. I wanted to delete in the fixture because I read it was a better practice to do the teardown in the fixture.

Comment: @dosas I'll take a look into that. I'm a noob on all the automation stuff, so thanks for the advice.

Comment: but this is not a tear down in the typical sense, your fixture only handles opening a file and providing the data in the file. does it need to delete the UUID after every test or at the end of all tests?

Comment: It should delete at the end of every test, since each call to the service generates and item in dynamo. And I want to delete it so we don't have unnecessary items in the DB. 

The fixture only opens the file because I could not find a way to send back the UUID to the fixture, other wise the method delete_test_data would be after the yield. Or maybe I would have created another fixture that handles the deleation.